# Login form redirects to login page when deployed on Render.com, but works locally

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, deployment, render.com

I have developed a web application using React.js and Express.js, and I'm experiencing a login issue when deploying the application on Render.com. Strangely, the application works perfectly fine when I run it locally without any issues.

When I try to log in to the dashboard of my deployed app on Render.com, the login form keeps redirecting me back to the login page. I inspected the browser console and found the following error message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs7IW.png)

Additionally, I checked the log files in the Render.com backend, and I found the following information:

```
POST /api/fishmongers/signin 200 2363.458 ms - 252
CustomError Details:
- StatusCode: 401
- Message: Not authorized, no token found
- ErrorCode: NO_TOKEN_FOUND
- Details: No token found in the request headers or cookies.
- Stack Trace: ...
```

Middleware/auth.js

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import Fishmonger from "../Models/fishmongers";
import CustomError from "../errors/CustomError";
require('dotenv').config();

export const protect = async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;

  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")
  ) {
    token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
  } else if (req.cookies.token) {
    token = req.cookies.token;
  }

  if (!token) {
    return next(new CustomError(401, "Not authorized, no token found", "NO_TOKEN_FOUND", "No token found in the request headers or cookies.", new Error().stack));
  }

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    const fishmonger = await Fishmonger.findById(decoded.id).select("-password");

    if (!fishmonger) {
      return next(
        new CustomError(
          404,
          "No fishmonger found with this ID",
          "FISHMONGER_NOT_FOUND",
          `Fishmonger with ID ${decoded.id} not found.`,
          new Error().stack
        )
      );
    }

    req.fishmonger = fishmonger;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof jwt.JsonWebTokenError) {
      return next(
        new CustomError(
          401,
          "Not authorized, invalid token",
          "INVALID_TOKEN",
          "The provided token is invalid or expired.",
          new Error().stack
        )
      );
    } else {
      next(error);
    }
  }
};
```

CheckAuthentication Function

```
 export const checkAuthentication = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axiosInstance.get(
        `${BACKEND_URL}/fishmongers/loggedin`,
        { withCredentials: true }
      );
  
      return response.status === 200;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error while checking authentication", error);
      toast.error("An error occurred while checking authentication. Please try again.");
      return false;
    }
  };
```

It seems that the authentication process is failing due to the absence of a token in the request headers or cookies, resulting in a 401 Unauthorized error.

What I've tried:

I double-checked my code for any discrepancies between the local version and the deployed version on Render.com, but I couldn't find any differences related to the authentication process.
I reviewed the authentication middleware in my Express.js backend to ensure that it properly handles tokens and authentication requests.
I checked the Render.com documentation and forums to see if there are any known issues or configurations specific to token-based authentication, but I couldn't find any relevant information.

What I was expecting:
When I log in to the dashboard of my deployed app on Render.com, I expect to be redirected to the dashboard page and successfully authenticate with the server, just like it works locally.

I'm confused about why this issue occurs only when deploying on Render.com but works perfectly fine locally. Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this behavior and suggest possible solutions?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. Please add your fetch function and your authentication middleware code with your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the token with header to be sure.

```
    const token = getToken(); // your custome method that returns token.
    const response = await axiosInstance.get(
      `${BACKEND_URL}/fishmongers/loggedin`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, 
        },
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    )
```

check if the Authorization token is present in your request when you are calling the api.